# Handling zooming and panning inside UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebview for loading the web pages in my application.

Since the UIWebView automatically supports the zooming and pinching effect, so it there any way to control this zooming and pinching effect?

I want to trace the scaling of the view?

**Is there any way to handle the zooming and panning inside the UIwebView ?**

Any suggestion is highly appreciated ....

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Very simple.

set the UIWebView's scalesPageToFit = YES;

http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/uiwebview-example-code/